# Length (Belgian) railway tracks

Tags: data-request, geospatial, europe, public-transport

Where can I find the length of the individual railway tracks in Belgium?

If you happen to know them for another country, please post them. It might interest someone else.

Comment: Did you consider to contact [INFRABEL](http://www.infrabel.be/)? To my knowledge, the old SNCB/NMBS was the only railway operator in Belgium with an own network. Some ten years ago, it was split. INFRABEL is the current infrastructure company.

Answer (score 1):

The [CIA World Factbook lists Belgium as having 3,592 km of standard gauge railways as of 2014](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/geos/be.html).

Wikipedia has a [List of countries by rail transport network size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_rail_transport_network_size), but it's not being maintained, so some entries are out of date.  (It lists Belgium as 3,233km as of 2008).

Comment: Thanks for this, Joe, but I was looking for the length of individual tracks. I edited my question for that.

Comment: @DirkHorsten : what do you consider to be 'individual tracks'?  Individual companies?  Runs between certain cities?  The length of individual metal rails that make up the track?

Comment: Runs between cities

Comment: @DirkHorsten : so are you interested in the length of track that you'd have to traverse, or the amount of track that's laid (typically at least double that, plus sidings, rail yards, etc.)

Comment: The official source is Infrabel's annual report: https://www.infrabel.be/sites/default/files/documents/facts_and_figures_2016-en.pdf

Comment: @thibautg that's 3602km as of 2016, then.  But the question's been modified so I'm now not sure exactly what's being asked.  A map with distances between cities might be closer to what they're looking for.

Comment: In fact, the annual report is misleading. 3602 the number of kilometres of main lines, not individual tracks. It seems to be a incorrect translation. A line can have one or two tracks. The number of kilometres of (individual) main tracks is 6511 in 2016. Source: internal key figures. Unfortunately Infrabel does not publish the geometry of tracks as open data.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably find it here:
https://metadata.geopunt.be/zoekdienst/apps/tabsearch/index.html?uuid=99C0DE2C-A5EA-4B6D-B0C4-2C61F71E080B
I think you need to contact the "Vlaamse overheid - Departement Ruimtelijke Ordening, Woonbeleid en Onroerend Erfgoed" to really get access to the data though.